# for loop executes in a weird way

Tags: awk, for

Quick question: I have to write a simple script and part of it is adding up every value in a column -> sum of every column and everything.
So file

```
1 2 5
1 2
1
```

should return

```
column1: 3
column2: 4
column3: 5
sum: 12
```

My code is almost perfect but columns are not displayed in ascending order

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  awk  '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i }; END { for (i in sum) print "column "i" : " sum[i];}' file.txt
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i;}; END {print "sum: " sum}' file.txt
fi
```

And the output is:

```
➜  script ./sum.sh
column 2 : 4
column 3 : 5
column 1 : 3
sum: 12
```

Why does it start with column 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (variable in array)` shall  iterate, assigning each index of array to variable in an unspecified order.

## Solution

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    awk '(NF>m){m=NF}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sum[i]+=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=m;i++)print("column "i" : "sum[i])}' file.txt
    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sum+=$i}END{print("sum: "sum)}' file.txt
fi
```

### Output

```
column 1 : 3
column 2 : 4
column 3 : 5
sum: 12
```

Comment: @codddeer123 See updated.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't think that I would come up with this idea